# PL/sql procedure with if and else issue

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to execute if else with stored procedure and getting error.Can anyone guide whats wrong.

```
Create or replace procedure schoolstudents(
    LS1 OUT NUMBER,
    LS2 OUT NUMBER,
    tablename in VARCHAR2)
IS
 lname     VARCHAR2(128);
 schoolId  NUMBER;
 my_sql VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  lname := tablename;
  schoolId := function(lname);
IF lname=0
  my_sql := 'Insert into sname values(''a'',''b'') RETURNING '||schoolId||', '||schoolId||' into :1, :2';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_sql RETURNING OUT LS1, LS2;
ELSE:
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE my_sql RETURNING OUT LS1, LS2;

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add the error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of problems. syntax for IF statement is

```
  IF  <condition> THEN
       stuff;
   ELSE
       other stuff;
  END IF;
```

2. if lname is not zero, then the my_sql variable is never assigned anything.
3. Do not concatenate literal values into the sql if they are going to change. use bind variables.  Otherwise, each new DML will have to be hard-parsed, and cause performance issues.
4. Lname is defined as VARCHAR2, but you are comparing it to a number literal.
5. schoolID is a number, but you are passing in characters.
6. There is no need to use execute immediate for any of this.  I don't know what the 2nd execute is supposed to be, but for the first one, just replace with:

(using example values of 100,200)

```
IF ...<whatever condition>... THEN
   LS1 :=  100;
   LS2 := 200;
    Insert into sname values( LS1,LS2);
```

If you have the values you are inserting, then you already know what to return.  RETURNING is useful if the DML is calling a sequence.nexval or some other function that returns a calculated/derived value.

I would highly recommend to read some pl/sql tutorials.